# How do I say it succinctly?

Tags: word-usage

In [one of my posts](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/24796/19860) I said

> There are 15 teams in each league in MLB regular season games, and 7 teams in each league in post season games.

I guess I said it clearly. How do I say it succinctly? Is this still clear?

> There are 15 teams in each league in MLB regular season games, and **7 in post season**.

Could someone please give a hint about **the rules/conventions of it**? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the number of teams in the league change, or just the number playing in the games? I don't know, but your expressions make it sound as if the number of teams in the league changes.  
If all teams stay in the league, then maybe the following would be more accurate:  
"Fifteen teams from each league play in MLB regular season games. The number from each league is trimmed to seven in post-season games."

Comment: Is "7 of 15 in each league advance to the next part" a clear expression?

Comment: Yes, once you fill in the blanks (teams, post-season). I think you need a written-out number at the start of a sentence.

Comment: @WXJ96163 Also remember to pay attention to articles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There are 15 teams per league in MLB regular season games, and 7 in post
>   season games.
>
> There are 15 teams per league in MLB regular season games, and 7 post
>   season.
>
> There are 15 and 7 teams per league in regular and post season
>   MLB games **respectively**.
>
> Regular and post season MLB games have 15 and 7 teams per league **respectively**.

All four sentences carry the same meaning. The third one sounds the most clear to me. The first two requires the reader to deduce the meaning based on the first part of the sentence.